# new font type in java

Tags: java, swing, fonts, awt

In my job we have to use an specific font type, is Futura std medium.

I have a JFrame where I write, and I need to do with this font type. I have the OTF document, but I cant find the way to import it in my code.

Comment: See [Importing Font to GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10418150/418556) for example code (& screen-shots).

Answer (score 7):

Did you try to check this answer about OTF in Java : 
[How to use Custom Font in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652344/how-can-i-use-a-custom-font-in-java)  and [Use OTF in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872569/how-to-use-open-type-fonts-in-java)

I think it could help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! it helps a lot! But I have an Exception which I cant understand, my code:

         InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/font/futura.otf");
         Font fontTitle2 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);

And the exception:

java.awt.FontFormatException: Unsupported sfnt C:\Users\RGOMEZ~1.ING\AppData\Local\Temp\+~JF2701312787789218051.tmp
 at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.init(Unknown Source)
 at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.font.FontManager.createFont2D(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Font.<init>(Unknown Source)
 
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can see an example about how to resolve it : http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/adding-a-ttf-font-from-an-inputstream-using-createfont-derivefont-613660.html
Could you accept my answer if it helped you ? Thanks.

Comment: I've found it before, but, I have 2 fonts and it only works with one of them. The other one:

nd the exception: java.awt.FontFormatException: Unsupported sfnt C:\Users\RGOMEZ~1.ING\AppData\Local\Temp\+~JF2701312787789218051.tmp