# Set Font type to Futura in Java

Tags: java, fonts

Every thing works fine except that it does not print Futura Font on the picture just a default looking font

```
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpeg"));
            Graphics g =image.getGraphics();
            g.setFont(new Font("Futura", Font.PLAIN, 45));
            g.drawString("Hello", 100, 440);

            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help :)

[new font type in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430898/new-font-type-in-java)

and this one: [How to use Open Type Fonts in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872569/how-to-use-open-type-fonts-in-java)

Follow links on 1st link